# How to copy std::vector<std::string> to GPU device with CUDA

Tags: c++, string, cuda, gpu, stdvector

I'm reading lines from a file, and want to perform some computation on each row by the GPU.

The problem that I'm facing is that up until now I used to copy an array of int in a constant size, now I have a vector of strings and each of them in a different size. I'm using:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
```

I have used a constant size to copy array. something like:

```
err = cudaMemcpy(_devArr, tmp, count * sizeof(unsigned int) * 8, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

But I'm not sure I fully get the idea how can it worked with vectors. How can I address and copy Vector of Strings? can I somehow copy it and still access it like an array with a thread+block index?

*Using the latest CUDA 10.2 and CUDA RTX 2060 graphic card

Comment: You can't. Strings are not supported on the GPU

Comment: Yeah I thought so... was looking for an alternative way to do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to flatten the strings down into a contiguous block of memory containing all the strings. My recommendation is to do it with two (total) blocks, one containing the combined string data, and one containing indexes for each of these strings.

```
std::string combined; //Works perfectly fine so long as it is contiguously allocated
std::vector<size_t> indexes; //You *might* be able to use int instead of size_t to save space
for(std::string const& line : lines) {
    combined += line;
    indexes.emplace_back(combined.size());
}
/* If 'lines' initially consisted of ["Dog", "Cat", "Tree", "Yard"], 'combined' is now
 * "DogCatTreeYard", and 'indexes' is now [3, 6, 10, 14].
 */

//I'm hoping I am writing these statements correctly; I don't specifically have CUDA experience
err = cudaMemcpy(_devArr, combined.data(), combined.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
err = cudaMemcpy(_devArr2, indexes.data(), indexes.size() * sizeof(size_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Then, in the device itself, you'll be able to read each string as you need them. I'm unfamiliar with the syntax that CUDA employs, so I'm going to write this in OpenCL syntax instead, but the principles should cleanly and directly translate over to CUDA; someone correct me if I'm mistaken.

```
kernel void main_func(
    global char * lines, //combined string data
    global ulong * indexes, //indexes telling us the beginning and end of each string
    ulong indexes_size, //number of strings being analyzed
    global int * results //space to return results back to Host
) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);//"Which String are we examining?"
    if(id >= indexes_size) //Bounds Checking
        return;
    global char * string; //Beginning of the string
    if(id == 0) //First String
        string = lines;
    else
        string = (lines + indexes[id-1]);
    global char * string_end = (lines + indexes[id]); //end of the string
    for(; string != string_end; string++) {
        if(*string == 'A') {
            results[id] = 1; //We matched the criteria; we'll put a '1' for this string
            return;
        }
    }
    results[id] = 0; //We did not match. We'll put a '0' for this string
}
```

The results of this code, executed on the initial list of strings, is that for any string that contains an `A`, it will get a result of 1; if it does not, it gets a result of 0. The logic here should be cleanly transferable to the particular syntax that CUDA uses; let me know if it is not.

Comment: wow thanks for the fully detailed explanation, good idea! I'll give it a try.. though there is a more easy intuitive way, but I guess it will do the work